# Embedding GATE and trying to compile and run StandAloneAnnie

Tags: java

I've been trying to learn GATE specifically ANNIE and TwitIE. I've seen a stand alone ANNIE java code found in the GATE website (https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java). I am trying to run the java file but I always get this error message (because I really don't understand how to embed GATE, please tell me how to step by step):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (gate.Gate).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" gate.util.GateRuntimeException: Could not infer installed plug-ins home!
Please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script.
    at gate.Gate.initLocalPaths(Gate.java:303)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:163)
    at StandAloneAnnie.main(StandAloneAnnie.java:81)
Java Result: 1
```

The problem comes from the statement:

```
Gate.init();
```

Please help, I badly need it. and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved the problem by including in the code before the initialization of GATE:
`Gate.init()`

these set of codes:

```
Properties props2 = System.getProperties();
props2.setProperty("gate.plugins.home", "C:\\Program Files\\GATE_Developer_8.0\\plugins");
Properties props3 = System.getProperties();
props3.setProperty("gate.site.config", "C:\\Program Files\\GATE_Developer_8.0\\gate.xml");
```

I hope this will also help others :)